# Why is numpy.array() is sometimes very slow?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using the numpy.array() function to create numpy.float64 ndarrays from lists.

I noticed that this is very slow when either the list contains None or a list of lists is provided.

Below are some examples with times.  There are obvious workarounds but why is this so slow?

Examples for list of None:

```
### Very slow to call array() with list of None
In [3]: %timeit numpy.array([None]*100000, dtype=numpy.float64)
1 loops, best of 3: 240 ms per loop

### Problem doesn't exist with array of zeroes
In [4]: %timeit numpy.array([0.0]*100000, dtype=numpy.float64)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.94 ms per loop

### Also fast if we use dtype=object and convert to float64
In [5]: %timeit numpy.array([None]*100000, dtype=numpy.object).astype(numpy.float64)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.92 ms per loop

### Also fast if we use fromiter() insead of array()
In [6]: %timeit numpy.fromiter([None]*100000, dtype=numpy.float64)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.29 ms per loop
```

Examples for list of lists:

```
### Very slow to create column matrix
In [7]: %timeit numpy.array([[0.0]]*100000, dtype=numpy.float64)
1 loops, best of 3: 353 ms per loop

### No problem to create column vector and reshape
In [8]: %timeit numpy.array([0.0]*100000, dtype=numpy.float64).reshape((-1,1))
100 loops, best of 3: 10 ms per loop

### Can use itertools to flatten input lists
In [9]: %timeit numpy.fromiter(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[0.0]]*100000),dtype=numpy.float64).reshape((-1,1))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.65 ms per loop
```

Comment: to create an empty array, use `a = numpy.empty(100000)`. To create an array with all zeros: `a = numpy.zeros(100000)`.

Comment: My goal isn't to create an array of zero's or empty, but I'm running into performance problems when None is in the data set.  If I create the array and first and set the values I have pretty much the same problem.  
    In [18]: a=numpy.empty((100000,))

    In [19]: %timeit a[:] = [None]*100000
    1 loops, best of 3: 209 ms per loop

    In [20]: %timeit a[:] = [0]*100000
    100 loops, best of 3: 9.59 ms per loop

Comment: actually it is an interesting question: why `[3]` is much slower than `[5]` (it might be a bug or just a rare use-case that is not optimized). To repeat `NaN`, call `numpy.repeat(float("nan"), 100000)`

Comment: Thanks JF, that is my question, why is [3] & [7] so slow, when the others are similar and so fast.  Our pyodbc database queries typically return lists of floats and None's which get put into ndarrays.  I would imagine this is not that rare a case.

Comment: It's also interesting that assigning a list of lists to an empty array (`a[...] = [[1]]*100000`)  is 50x slower than `[8]` (assigning a row is fast). I guess finding the bottleneck involves profiling C code... At any rate, this is a good question.

Comment: NumPy is by no means perfect. Travis Oliphant, the original authors of NumPy, says that is full of rather ugly C code that can be improved and made faster, much faster at places.

Comment: Clearly.  It seems useful to let others know about this, and to see if anyone else has come across this particular issue. I'll dig deeper into the C code.

Answer (score 3):

I've reported this as a numpy issue.  The report and patch files are here:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3392

After patching:

```
# was 240 ms, best alternate version was 3.29
In [5]: %timeit numpy.array([None]*100000)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.49 ms per loop

# was 353 ms, best alternate version was 9.65
In [6]: %timeit numpy.array([[0.0]]*100000)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.7 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the code for converting lists just calls `float` on everything. If the argument defines `__float__`, we call that, otherwise we treat it like a string (throwing an exception on None, we catch that and puts in `np.nan`). The exception handling should be relatively slower.

Timing seems to verify this hypothesis:

```
import numpy as np
%timeit [None] * 100000
> 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop

%timeit np.array([0.0] * 100000)
> 10 loops, best of 3: 21.3 ms per loop
%timeit [i.__float__() for i in [0.0] * 100000]
> 10 loops, best of 3: 32 ms per loop


def flt(d):
    try:
        return float(d)
    except:
        return np.nan

%timeit np.array([None] * 100000, dtype=np.float64)
> 1 loops, best of 3: 477 ms per loop    
%timeit [flt(d) for d in [None] * 100000]
> 1 loops, best of 3: 328 ms per loop
```

Adding another case just to be obvious about where I'm going with this. If there was an explicit check for None, it would not be this slow above:

```
def flt2(d):                              
    if d is None:
        return np.nan
    try:
        return float(d)
    except:
        return np.nan

%timeit [flt2(d) for d in [None] * 100000]
> 10 loops, best of 3: 45 ms per loop
```

Comment: I found your hypothesis very interesting, although the timing differences that you are getting (about 1.5X faster) are still not supporting your arguments since the OP's timing differences are about 35X.... you could maybe keep working in this direction

Comment: @sgpc Yeah, if I wanted to dig deeper the next step is looking at the source. Although I do know: if they were explicitly checking for `None`, it would not be this slow.

Comment: I dug deeper.  The code is spending all of its time throwing execeptions.  It's not treating things as strings so much as calling getattr or getbuffer for lots of things that don't have the attribute or aren't buffers.  Both of these create and ignore exceptions.  I tweaked common.c and ctor.c to avoid these cases and performance is more like what you would expect.