# Jupyter Kernel is busy after code execution

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter Notebook with conda and Python 3. Recently, the kernel is busy even after the code execution is finished and the execution time is way longer than usual. I have been searching around but there is no result. Any suggestions?

Edit: I'm sorry for being too general. I am trying to identify the problem myself so any direction will be appreciated. After re-running the code a few times, it seems like whenever I run the following block of code, it happens:

```
train_X = np.array(train_X)
train_Y = np.array(train_Y)
```

The previous code is as following:

```
# In[1]:    
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict    

# In[2]:   
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
people_list = df['ID'].unique()
product_list = df['product'].unique() 

# Out[2]:
    ID  product     M1  M2  M3  class
0   0   A           1   2   6   1
1   1   B           2   3   7   1
2   2   C           3   4   3   0
3   0   C           4   3   2   1
4   1   A           5   4   3   1
5   2   B           6   6   1   0  

# In[3]:    
people_dict = {}
target_dict = {}

for i in range(len(people_list)):
    key = people_list[i]
    new_df = df[df['ID'] == people_list[i]]
    new_df = new_df.transpose()
    new_df.columns = new_df.iloc[1]
    new_df = new_df[2:-1]   
    people_dict[key] = new_df
    target_dict[key] = df.iat[i, 5]

for key in people_dict.keys():
    for i in product_list:
        if i not in people_dict[key].columns:
            people_dict[key][i] = [0]*3
    people_dict[key] = people_dict[key].reindex(sorted(people_dict[key].columns), axis = 1)

# In[5]:    
people_values = OrderedDict()
target_values = OrderedDict()

# extract the value of the dataframe
for key in people_dict.keys():
    people_values[key] = people_dict[key].values
    target_values[key] = target_dict[key]

# In[6]:
n_samples = 1
timestes = 3
n_features = 3

train_input = list(people_values.values())
train_target = list(target_values.values())

train_X = []
train_Y = []

for i in range(len(train_input)):
    train_X.append(train_input[i])
    train_Y.append(train_target[i])

# In[7]:
train_X = np.array(train_X)
train_Y = np.array(train_Y)
```

Essentially, I am trying to do some classification with Keras LSTM and the input is historical sales of 1 person, the output is their class, 'good' or 'bad'.

The real dataset has 60k rows but I simplified the dataset so everyone can follow more easily. When I worked with this dataset previously, I never encountered this issue.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Unless you be more specific, it is impossible for anyone here to help...

Comment: Your question is hard for us to answer because it is so general. It would be very helpful for us if you can isolate the problem and share the problematic code with us. For example, copy the `.ipynb` file that seems to be giving you problems and then start removing parts of it until you get a small piece of code that still causes the issue. Then if you post that code, we can probably help you debug it.

Comment: @Christopher Bottoms: thank you, I just edited and added more details to the question. I tried to run each cell again and it seems like that 2 lines were the issue.

Comment: @desertnaut: I'm sorry for not being more specific. I tried to add more details to my question.

Comment: Good; downvote removed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it is just an issue with converting a variable to a numpy array, as it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819261/why-is-numpy-array-is-sometimes-very-slow). I just worked around it.